# htaccess pretty url and force www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, pretty-urls

I've been using following code to achieve pretty urls:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

And it is working fine.

However, I also need to force my domain to redirect to www while keeping pretty urls.

I've read through some threads that ask for redirection to www, but I am unable to implement it together with pretty url (`domain.com -> www.domain.com`, `domain.com/news -> www.domain.com/news` respectively).

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Can you show the rule you tried for adding `www`

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ht tp://www.example.com/index.php?p=$1 [L,R=301,NC] Sorry, fighting with comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `www` redirect rule before rewrite rule you already have:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```